# How can I add objects into an array iteratively

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of objects of type GameObject whose names are arrow1, arrow2, arrow3... and I want to push them into a list/array iteratively in a script, instead of doing

arrows.Add(arrow1);
arrows.Add(arrow2);
...

How could I do it to save those lines of code by copying and pasting the same thing all the time?

Thank you! *(Sorry for leaving too much evidence that I am a noob at this).*

Comment: You can declare a list or array with the objects you like `List<GameObject> arrowList = new List<GameObject>{arrow1, arrow2, arrow3, ..., arrowX};`. If this is an already existing list, you can create this list then append it to another list `originalList.AddRange(arrowList)`. Is there a reason you need to feed in these objects as individuals to your script? Can you not just serialize a list and drag them in?

Comment: Instead of having `arrow1`, `arrow2`, `arrow3`, why don't you remove those and explicitly have an array to begin with, and access it like `arrows[0]`, `arrows[1]`, `arrows[2]`?

Answer (score 0):

FindGameObjectsWithTag() might be your best option. Add a tag of "arrow" to your arrow objects and define an empty list and you should be good to go with this kind of code:

```
private List<GameObject> arrows = new List<GameObject>();

arrows = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("arrow");
```

Hope this is helpful!